# A way to find if multiple keys exist under the same name?

Tags: python

Ok so im making this discord bot that uses the Google Calendar API to get my events, when I call the command in discord it will give me a list of my events for the week. It works fine for getting only one event, but since each event has the same key names in the json im finding it hard to find if multiple keys exist within the json file, exp.

```
[
{
    "created": "2020-05-05T18:30:24.000Z",
    "creator": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": true
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-05T15:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "etag": "\"3177446035674000\"",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MWZqdXRqZW9panZ0YmZycDVnZ2R1OG1kbnAgcHJvamVjdG5vdGlmeWNhbEBt",
    "iCalUID": "1fjutjeoijvtbfrp5ggdu8mdnp@google.com",
    "id": "1fjutjeoijvtbfrp5ggdu8mdnp",
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "organizer": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": true
    },
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": true
    },
    "sequence": 0,
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-05T14:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "status": "confirmed",
    "summary": "Event title 1",
    "updated": "2020-05-05T23:56:57.837Z"
},
{
    "created": "2020-05-06T17:48:42.000Z",
    "creator": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": true
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-06T15:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "etag": "\"3177575538452000\"",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MmtzdDVyb29mZzhydGhyb25ja2UxazVkbmcgcHJvamVjdG5vdGlmeWNhbEBt",
    "iCalUID": "2kst5roofg8rthroncke1k5dng@google.com",
    "id": "2kst5roofg8rthroncke1k5dng",
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "organizer": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": true
    },
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": true
    },
    "sequence": 1,
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-06T14:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "status": "confirmed",
    "summary": "Event title 2",
    "updated": "2020-05-06T17:56:09.226Z"
}
```

So as you can see there are 2 keys for each event, the key I want to use is the "summary" key to get the event name.

In my code, its fine for getting the first key, but in the nature of the program, there may be lots of events for a given week, so how can I test if there are multiple keys, then if there are, print the others, if there arent, print saying there arent any more events. This is what I have so far:

```
#use google calendar api token
    import pickle
    credentials = pickle.load(open('token.pickle', 'rb'))
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    #get id (aka calendar name)
    calendar_list = service.calendarList().list().execute()
    calendar_id = calendar_list['items'][0]['id']

    #get items from id
    calendar_list = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id).execute()
    #print(calendar_list['items'])

    #making json
    loadjson = json.dumps(calendar_list['items'])
    info = json.loads(loadjson)

    with open("formatteddata.json", "w") as formatted_data:
        json.dump(info, formatted_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)


    #print title of event (item name)
    itemtitle = info[0]["summary"]
    print (itemtitle)

    if ["summary"][1] in loadjson:
        print("2 exist")
    else:
        print('does not exist')
```

The end portion is what Im having trouble with. I get a list index out of range error, not sure if I have the right idea or if im super far off

Comment: `info` is the array of item dicts, so use `info[n]["summary"]` to get the summary associated with the n'th item.

Comment: ```events = [ event["summary"] for event in info if "summary" in event ]```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you need:

```
inputData = [
{
    "created": "2020-05-05T18:30:24.000Z",
    "creator": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": "true"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-05T15:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "etag": "\"3177446035674000\"",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MWZqdXRqZW9panZ0YmZycDVnZ2R1OG1kbnAgcHJvamVjdG5vdGlmeWNhbEBt",
    "iCalUID": "1fjutjeoijvtbfrp5ggdu8mdnp@google.com",
    "id": "1fjutjeoijvtbfrp5ggdu8mdnp",
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "organizer": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": "true"
    },
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": "true"
    },
    "sequence": 0,
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-05T14:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "status": "confirmed",
    "summary": "Event title 1",
    "updated": "2020-05-05T23:56:57.837Z"
},
{
    "created": "2020-05-06T17:48:42.000Z",
    "creator": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": "true"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-06T15:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "etag": "\"3177575538452000\"",
    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MmtzdDVyb29mZzhydGhyb25ja2UxazVkbmcgcHJvamVjdG5vdGlmeWNhbEBt",
    "iCalUID": "2kst5roofg8rthroncke1k5dng@google.com",
    "id": "2kst5roofg8rthroncke1k5dng",
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "organizer": {
        "email": "email goes here",
        "self": "true"
    },
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": "true"
    },
    "sequence": 1,
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-05-06T14:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "status": "confirmed",
    "summary": "Event title 2",
    "updated": "2020-05-06T17:56:09.226Z"
}
]


#print title of event (item name)
itemtitle = inputData[0]["summary"]
print (itemtitle)

counter = 0

for event in inputData:
  if "summary" in event:
      counter = counter + 1

if counter > 0: 
  outputMsg = str(counter) + " exist"
else:
  outputMsg = "does not exist"

print(outputMsg)
```